# Make menu item hover colour extend to the edges of the menu

Tags: html, css, menu

I am making a menu and I want the hovercolour of the links (in this case 'Urenportaal') to fill up the space above and around the button. Right now it displays a square within the menu. I want it to touch to border of the menu. How can I fix this?

Current code:

```css
.easyflexMenu {
  width: 150px;
  height: 500px;
  float: left;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #229dfc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /*bolling van de hoeken*/
  padding: 10px;
}

.easyflexMenu a {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 3px 0px 3px 5px;
  width: 145px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #229dfc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
}

.easyflexMenu a:active {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.easyflexMenu a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

li {
  display: list-item;
  text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}

.easyflexMenu ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul,
menu,
dir {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: disc;
  -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
  -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
  -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
  -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
  -webkit-padding-start: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="efmainmenu" class="easyflexMenu">
  <ul>
    <li id="urenportaal"><a href="urenportaal.tpsp?action=list&amp;s=79506f49627169694f7a30775150444c376a686770773d3d">Urenportaal</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use transform scale:

```
.easyflexMenu a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transform: scale(1.14);
  width: 144.5px;
}
```

In your case, you needed to change the width a bit to make it fit

```css
.easyflexMenu {
  width: 150px;
  height: 500px;
  float: left;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #229dfc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /*bolling van de hoeken*/
  padding: 10px;
}

.easyflexMenu a {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 3px 0px 3px 5px;
  width: 145px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #229dfc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
}

.easyflexMenu a:active {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.easyflexMenu a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transform: scale(1.14);
  width: 144.5px;
}

li {
  display: list-item;
  text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}

.easyflexMenu ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul,
menu,
dir {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: disc;
  -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
  -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
  -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
  -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
  -webkit-padding-start: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="efmainmenu" class="easyflexMenu">
  <ul>
    <li id="urenportaal"><a href="urenportaal.tpsp?action=list&amp;s=79506f49627169694f7a30775150444c376a686770773d3d">Urenportaal</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: He wanted to remove the padding of ul and anchors should touch the borders. Not transformation.

Comment: @Krishna9960 And what did the OP say to imply that?

Comment: Though your output achieves what he is expecting..but is that what he wants ?

Comment: @Krishna9960 Apparently it is.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a slight negative margin and higher padding to *.easyflexMenu a.*

Answer (score 0):

```
.easyflexMenu {
    width: 150px;
    height: 500px;
    float: left;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #229dfc;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.easyflexMenu a{
    margin: 0px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #229dfc;
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
}
```

Update your CSS classes as above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following in `a:hover`

1. Remove the padding set in the containing div by adding a negative margin using `margin: -10px`
2. To have the text stay in the same position, overwrite your `a:hover` padding with one where you add 10px of padding. `padding: 13px 10px 13px 15px;`

Your a:hover should now look like this:

```
.easyflexMenu a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  margin: -10px;
  padding: 13px 10px 13px 15px;
}
```

If this is not the behaviour you want when there are more items in the list, you can tweak those values. For example if you only want the padding to go out to the borders, you could use this instead:

```
.easyflexMenu a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  margin: 0px -10px 0px -10px;
  padding: 3px 10px 3px 15px;
}
```